# Storing image / file path in database; starts with / (forward slash) or no?

Tags: database, conventions

When storing path to an image or file in database, is it better to store the path that starts with `/` (forward slash) or without `/`? For example:

1. `/user/1.jpg` (Then the `BASE_URL` will be `https://example.com/img`)
2. `user/1.jpg` (Then the `BASE_URL` will be `https://example.com/img/`)

Which is better or the correct way? Is there any convention / best practices for this? Or is it just a personal preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with `user/1.jpg`, because if it starts with `/`, it looks like an absolute path instead.